# list and change supported keyboard layout in Linux 2.4.22

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a RAID management software running on a Linux LiveCD which uses Linux 2.4.22. It uses US kayboard layout by default, but I would like to change this to SE(Sweden) layout. Layouts should be loaded with *loadkeys* utility, but SE layout seems to be missing: [image: http://s2.postimage.org/x0tkmetax/keyboard.png]

How can I view supported keyboard layouts? And how to change those in Linux 2.4.22?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on which distribution your live cd is based.
Check this page, you will find reference about how to change the keyboard layout on the most common linux distributions : http://www.howtoforge.com/changing-language-and-keyboard-layout-on-various-linux-distributions